# 23.04 wrong scaling with dual monitor setup with internal 4k screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I've been running this dual monitor setup on 22.10:

- Internal: 3840 x 2160, scaling 200 %
- External: 3440 x 1440, scaling 100 %

This has been working nicely in 22.10 i.e. apps switched the scaling depending on the screen.

Since 23.04 this is no more working i.e. apps use either 100 % or 200 % and stay that way when moving to the other screen. My non-satisfying workaround is setting the internal resolution to 1920 x 1080.

Is there a setting to re-enable auto-scaling when moving apps between screens?